# Declaration of iterator: "does not contain a type"

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, queue

I am having difficulty understanding why I am getting this error. I am referring to both Josuttis' STL book and other resources and it seems that the way I have declared my iterator below should work:

```
#ifndef LRU_H
#define LRU_H

#include <queue>
#include <iterator>


class LRU
{
public:

   LRU();                           // default constructor
   LRU(int);                        // constructor with argument
   ~LRU();                          // destructor 

   // Methods
   //
   void enqueue(int);               // add datum to the queue
   void dequeue();                  // remove datum from the queue
   void replace();                  // replacement algorithm
   void displayQueue() const;       // display contents of queue

private:

   // Member Data
   //
   const int MAX_SIZE;
   int m_currentCount;

   std::queue<int> m_buffer;
   std::queue<int>::const_iterator iter;

};

#endif
```

But the line where I declare my const_iterator generates the following compiler error:

```
In file included from main.cpp:10:
lru.h:41: error: 'const_iterator' in class 'std::queue<int, std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> > >' does not name a type
In file included from lru.cpp:10:
lru.h:41: error: 'const_iterator' in class 'std::queue<int, std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> > >' does not name a type
lru.cpp: In constructor 'LRU::LRU()':
lru.cpp:17: error: class 'LRU' does not have any field named 'm_pos'
lru.cpp: In constructor 'LRU::LRU(int)':
lru.cpp:23: error: class 'LRU' does not have any field named 'm_pos'

Compilation exited abnormally with code 1 at Thu Nov 15 10:47:31
```

Is there something special about declaring an iterator in a class that results in the error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The container adapter [`std::queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) has no publicly accessible iterators. Since the `std::queue<int>` is hidden in the `LRU` implementation, you could consider using an [`std::deque<int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) instead. `std::deque` is the default container used by `std::queue` under the hood, so you would incur no performance penalty by using it. I think it is safe to use it as long as you do not make the non-queue operations public in your `LRU` interface.

Comment: I see. I probably should have known that earlier. I guess it makes sense given the nature of the queue data structure. Is there an internal iterator for queue that will simply allow read access? I just want a method to display the contents of the queue.

Comment: No, you have no access to the internals. But you could use `std::deque`, and make sure not to make any non-queue like access public.